# Does encoding of pdf affect text order?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to parsing journal articles PDF.
normally parsing text in PDF(just text) works fine.
but parsing Korean article PDF have some problems.
other problems are not a big deal. but incorrect text order is a big deal.

here is sample.

original text

```
열 노출에 의한 IN738LC의 기계적 특성 및 미세조직 변화
```

PDF parsing library :

```
열 노출에 의한의 기계적 특성 및 미세조직 변화IN738LC
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltROW.png)
english text between korean goes backwards.
for test, I opened this pdf by pdf.JS in web. and I got a same result.
so I was about to give up.

but in Chrome pdf viewer and Mac preview showed the result in the correct order of the sentence.

I have no idea what is problem. I'm vaguely thinking it's an encoding problem.

So I want to know why this problem occurs.

Comment: This depends on the *"PDF parsing library"* and the options you use for parsing with it.

Comment: @mkl So I wonder what kind of options (encoding, etc) affect the order of the text. It occurs not only in the parsing process, but also copying text in pdf viewer software(like sumatraPDF). what is the difference between Chrome pdf viewer, Mac preview and any other things?

Comment: The instructions in a PDF that draw characters on a page may drawn them in any order. It may be the natural reading order, but it may also for example first draw all text using one font, then all text using another one. Consequentially, there also are different strategies for text extraction, the text may be returned in the order it is drawn (hoping for it to be drawn in the natural reading order) or the text may be sorted before being returned. And sorting algorithms may sort in different ways. Additionally there may be extra tagging information which can be used or ignored.

Comment: @mkl thanks! I fully understand what you say.